# How to permanently remove the notebook from new Team Site builds?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, team-sites

Each time I build a SharePoint Online team site a shared notebook (OneNote) document is added into the site and available for all users.

What would be the best approach for permanently preventing this from happening across multiple tenants and site collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can edit a default Teamsite template in SharePoint Online environment.

A clumsy workaround would be to:

1. Create a new site.
2. Open the site and navigate to home page.
3. Edit the Menu on the left and remove Notebook link.
4. Save the site as a template.
5. Use the template for creating new sites.

Similarly, if you are creating a site programmatically, you can remove the link at this stage. The Notebook is not available under Site Content, so there will be no way of using it, short of contacting Microsoft for a site collection restore.